# MNIST attribute-error while loading dataset

Tags: python, mnist

I'm working with python 3.5 and tensorflow on Windows. I wrote a script where I get the MNIST data from the idx files and it works fine. I was able to open single images. Today I opened my Project and now I am having the following issue:

```
  File "C:\Users\uidj8441\Documents\PYTHON\0_projects\open MNIST data\open_mnist
_data\open_mnist_data\open_mnist_data.py", line 27, in <module>
    images, labels = mnist.load_training()              #training set
AttributeError: 'Datasets' object has no attribute 'load_training'
```

I don't know where this problem is coming from. See my complete code below:

```
#### libaries
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from mnist import MNIST
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'        #deactivate warnings

#### set and print working folder
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\uidj8441\\Documents\\PYTHON\\0_projects\\open MNIST data\\open_mnist_data\\open_mnist_data')
print('working folder:\n\n',os.getcwd(),'\n')

#### load dataset (training or test)
## a) offline-download: from idx1 / idx3 files
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('C:\\Users\\uidj8441\\Documents\\PYTHON\\0_projects\\open MNIST data\\open_mnist_data\\open_mnist_data\\',one_hot=True)

## b) online-download via (firewall might be blocking)
#from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
#mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

images, labels = mnist.load_training()      #training set
#images, labels = mnist.load_testing()      #test set

#### display random image
print('\nLoading random image and display\n')
index=random.randrange(0,len(images))
print('Random image with index',index,'is a:',labels[index])
print(mnist.display(images[index]))

#### display explicit image
img_num=8
print('\n Chosen image with index',img_num, 'is a:',labels[img_num])
print(mnist.display(images[img_num]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command...

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('C:\\Users\\uidj8441\\Documents\\PYTHON\\0_projects\\open MNIST data\\open_mnist_data\\open_mnist_data\\',one_hot=True)
```

... download the `MNIST` datasets from Google servers, put the compressed files into your folder `C:\\Users\\uidj8441\\Documents\\PYTHON\\0_projects\\open MNIST data\\open_mnist_data\\open_mnist_data\\` and encode the targets as `one_hot`.

Now, you can access the 3 datasets, namely `train`, `test`, `validation`.

E.g. at train stage, your command will start with `mnist.train.{something}`, versus `mnist.{something}` that you are doing in your code above.